# What is the meaning of "aggregate state" within the context of RPA?

Tags: fuel, rpa

I'm trying to make a new entry in the thermodynamic database of RPA (Rocket Propulsion Analysis, http://w.lpre.de/) and you are required to provide an "aggregate state".

For CEA (Chemical Equilibrium with Applications) I thought this normally just meant to pick the state (solid/liquid/gas) for the propellant at normal conditions, but for RPA the options are

- gaseous
- condensed 1
- condensed 2
- condensed 3

and I am unsure what those mean. Next to the entry field it says the following

> condensed phases are numbered in increasing order by temperature.

With some googling I guess it could mean the order of states besides gaseous for a given propellant?

When clicking through some entries H<sub>2</sub>O was given as condensed 2, while aqueous 98% H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> was given condensed 1 as aggregate state, but so are a lot of solid propellant entries??

For sodium sulfate (Na<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>) three different crystal structures (V, IV, I) are numbered condensed 1 to 3, while its liquid entry has an empty "aggregate state" (which isn't an option for new entries??).

So what do these different condensed phases as options for "aggregate state" mean in the context of rocket propellants?